# Generating Object UML diagrams from java program

Tags: java, object, uml, object-diagram

Is there a way I could generate [Object UML diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_diagram) from the `.jar` file I have created for my project. I want to supply the input to the jar and then have the Object UML diagrams generated. To generate and visualise the class diagrams, I used [class-visualizer](http://www.class-visualizer.net/) but could not find a tool for object-uml diagrams generation.

Comment: tons of tools to do that, but what's the point? your code should be based on decent (UML or other) diagrams, not vice versa

Comment: @Stultuske I am learning about UML diagrams and want to analyse the design this way. Could you point me towards a tool that will help generate object uml diagrams?

Comment: @xmojmr There is a difference between class UML diagrams and object UML diagrams. Please remove the duplicate marking.

Comment: again, don't do that, especially not if you want to learn how to do it decently. UML is meant to be clear, precise, and show you exactly how your code should be ordganized. If you generate the UML, all you get (best case scenario) is how it is organized. kind of defeats the entire purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Object and Class diagrams are two different things. There are several tools that can do static analysis of your source code to put together a Class diagram for you (I.e. class *structure*). For an object diagram you need something that can hook into the process at runtime, when the Objects are in memory. Sparx EA can do this —- it can attach to processes that emit debug symbols to build a picture of the objects in memory and the interactions between them, though of course it can only do that for objects exercised by the process during the capture session. It builds a sequence chart rather than an object diagram, but it will nonetheless help you with object *behaviour*.